# Wrote a code but there are some errors

Tags: c, if-statement, random, void

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int randomNumber(int);
void checkNumber(float,float);
int main()
{

    int number ,guess = 0,check=0;
    char choice='Y';
    number = randomNumber();
    printf("%d\n",number);

    while(1)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'Y':
                printf("Guess the number that is between 1-20:\n");
                scanf("%d",&guess);
                checkNumber(number,guess);
                break;
            case 'N'
                printf("BYE BYE....\n")
                break;
            default:
            printf("Please enter a valid choice\n");
        }
        if(check==0 && choice == 0 'Y')
        {
            printf("***********\nDo you want to contiune to guess number?(Y/N)\n");
            scanf("%c",&choice);
            printf("***********\n");

        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;
    int randomNumber()
    {
        return (rand()%10)
    }
}

void checkNumber()

if (n<g)
{
    printf("Guess a lower value!\n\n");
    return 0;
}

else if (n<g)
{
    printf("Guess a higher value!\n\n");
    return 0;
}
else
{
    printf("****Cong.,You guessed the number ****\n\n");
    return 1;
}
```

a program to get the user to guess the number that the program has picked as the lucky number. It uses one for loop and plenty of if statements but there are some logical or syntax errors.I couldn't solve the problem.any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(check==0 && choice == 0 'Y')` ?????? this should have to be `if(check==0 && choice == 'Y')`

Comment: I could not test it, but just looking to the code I see that you're missing curly brackets around your checkNumber function code, and there are missing the arguments for the function checkNumber(int n, int g)

Comment: `checkNumber()` function you have defined without parameters and even not used brackets.

Comment: also, there is `if (n<g)` followed by `else if (n<g)`

Comment: `void checkNumber()` return type is void, whereas you are returning integer value.

Comment: In the 4th line in main() function you are displaying the number. I don't think user will find any difficulty to guess the number. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is very bad and it doesn't even compile.
I think this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int randomNumber();
int checkNumber(int,int);
int main()
{

    int number ,guess = 0,check=0;
    char choice='Y';
    number = randomNumber();
    printf("%d\n",number);

    while(1)
    {
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 'Y':
                printf("Guess the number that is between 1-20:\n");
                scanf("%d",&guess);
                checkNumber(number,guess);
                break;
            case 'N':
                printf("BYE BYE....\n")
                break;
            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid choice\n");
        }
        if(check==0 && choice == 'Y')
        {
            printf("***********\nDo you want to continue to guess number?(Y/N)\n");
            scanf("%c",&choice);
            printf("***********\n");

        }
        else break;
    }
    return 0;

}
    int randomNumber(){

        return (rand()%10);
    }

    int checkNumber(int n, int g){

        if (n<g)
        {
            printf("Guess a lower value!\n\n");
            return 0;
        }

        else if (n>g)
        {
            printf("Guess a higher value\n\n");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("****Cong.,You guessed the number ****\n\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't fix the forward declarations: `checkNumber` is declared with two `float` arguments, while it actually takes two `int`s, and `randomNumber` is declared with an `int` argument while the actual function does not take any arg.

Comment: Yeah i already fixed some of what you mentioned and the rest just now:)

Comment: you forgot to add `;` in the return statement of `randomNumber()`